# Swift: Trying to control time in AVAudioPlayerNode using UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, seekbar, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I'm using an `AVAudioPlayerNode` attached to an `AVAudioEngine` to play a sound.

to get the current time of the player I'm doing this:

```
extension AVAudioPlayerNode {
var currentTime: TimeInterval {
    get {
        if let nodeTime: AVAudioTime = self.lastRenderTime, let playerTime: AVAudioTime = self.playerTime(forNodeTime: nodeTime) {
            return Double(playerTime.sampleTime) / playerTime.sampleRate
        }
        return 0
    }
 }

}
```

I have a slider that indicates the current time of the audio. When the user changes the slider value, on `.ended` event I have to change the current time of the player to that indicated in the slider. 
To do so:

```
extension AVAudioPlayerNode {

func seekTo(value: Float, audioFile: AVAudioFile, duration: Float) {
    if let nodetime = self.lastRenderTime{
        let playerTime: AVAudioTime = self.playerTime(forNodeTime: nodetime)!
        let sampleRate = self.outputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate
        let newsampletime = AVAudioFramePosition(Int(sampleRate * Double(value)))
        let length = duration - value
        let framestoplay = AVAudioFrameCount(Float(playerTime.sampleRate) * length)
        self.stop()

        if framestoplay > 1000 {
            self.scheduleSegment(audioFile, startingFrame: newsampletime, frameCount: framestoplay, at: nil,completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    self.play()
}
```

However, my function `seekTo` is not working correctly(I'm printing currentTime before and after the function and it shows always a negative value ~= -0.02). What is the wrong thing I'm doing and can I find a simpler way to change the currentTime of the player?

Comment: you can use it in simple way by use slider and define a timer and if you want handle tap and drag seek its better define tap gesture and use slider action.

Comment: Thanks for your try @masoud but you did not answer my question. What u said is already implemented. But what I want is, after changing the slider value, how can i change the current time of the player.

Comment: Any solution how to change current time ???

Comment: @ShamDass not ye, if u found anything please answer this question

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue. Apparently the `framestoplay` was always 0, which happened because of `sampleRate`. The value for `playerTime.sampleRate` was always 0 in my case.

So,

```
let framestoplay = AVAudioFrameCount(Float(playerTime.sampleRate) * length)
```

must be replaced with

```
let framestoplay = AVAudioFrameCount(Float(sampleRate) * length)
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69632925/5709159

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Sorry, I have not encountered such issue before. Maybe if you link a sample working project to your question, you may receive more response.